# Proc Optmodel MILP solver, how to find infeasible constraints

Tags: sas

I am trying to build an optimization model using proc optmodel. I am using MILP solver and im getting into infeasible solution again and again.

Problem happens when pre solver can't get the conflicting constraint, I dont get any info in log regarding where to go and do edits and its a long and tedious process of figuring out among 1000's of constraints.

Please advice if there is a way to identify the infeasible constraints after a solve run.

I have tried using IIS option which doesnt work for MILP solver, PRESTOL option to get even the slightest infeasible constraints but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the MILP solver is able to identify a specific constraint that is causing infeasibility, it will show up in the log. i.e.:

`Note: Constraint con[1] causes the problem to be infeasible.`

If it can't, it will tell you that the problem itself is infeasible. To find out the exact constraint causing the problem, you can remove constraints and loop the solver until it becomes feasible. See [this answer](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/IIS-Option/m-p/94886#M623) for more information. Example code below:

```
proc optmodel presolver=none;
   /* declare variables */
   var x{1..3} >=0;

   /* upper bound on variable x[3] */
   x[3].ub = 3;

   /* objective function */
   min obj = x[1] + x[2] + x[3];

   /* constraints */
   con c1: x[1] + x[2] >= 10;
   con c2: x[1] + x[3] <= 4;
   con c3: 4 <= x[2] + x[3] <= 5;

   num iteration init 1;
   set IIS{1 .. iteration} init {};
   do while (1);
     solve with lp / iis = on;
     IIS[iteration] = {ci in 1 .. _NCON_: _CON_[ci].status ~= ''};
     if card(IIS[iteration]) = 0 then leave;
     for {ci in IIS[iteration]: _CON_[ci].status = 'I_L'}
        _CON_[ci].lb = -constant('big');
     for {ci in IIS[iteration]: _CON_[ci].status = 'I_U'}
        _CON_[ci].ub = constant('big');
     iteration = iteration + 1;
   end;
   iteration = iteration - 1;
   for {ii in 1 .. iteration}
     put IIS[ii]=;
quit;
```

Source: [LeoLopes](https://communities.sas.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/3067), SAS Community Forum

Comment: I have tried using the IIS option, the problem is that IIS options is not valid if you try to solve with milp. Which is what I am doing... is there any other method which can be utilized for the same.

Comment: While the solution is not ideal, the above looping method should provide you with good direction on approximately where it is failing. The MILP solver already uses LP relaxations for most of its branching cuts.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to find out the infeasibility using MILP solver? 

Also, is there a way to get the constraint which is printed in log by MILP solver in sas itself, it must be stored in a macro variable somewhere.